# HIbernate ignore fetching data from OnetoMany field

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I would like to ignore `@OnetoMany` field in my entity. fetch data need to get actual fields but don't want to fire query to dependent table. But deleting data from parent table needs deletion from dependent table

I have tried `@Transient` that ignores but the delete is also being ignored. Is there any other option to tell JPA not to fetch data from childs table when i call the parent entity?

```
@Entity
Table(name = "User")
public class UserEntity implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "SERIAL", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String serial;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "serialBySerialId", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<UserActionEntity> userActionsById;

}

@Table(name = "user_action")
public class UserActionEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "action")
    private String action;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID", nullable = false)
    private UserEntity userByUserId;
```

Comment: Can you post the source code?

Comment: @Christine added the source code

Comment: Where is the code that deletes the entity?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to fire query to dependent table, you can use (fetch = FetchType.LAZY) on UserActionEntity property.

```
 @OneToMany(mappedBy = "serialBySerialId", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        private Set<UserActionEntity> userActionsById;
```